# How to convert CSV file to HTML format with folding&unfolding function

Tags: powershell

I have a big CSV table (more than 2000+ records)

1. Is it possible to convert to HTML format?
2. We also want the data inside the HTML file able to fold&Unfold

Like below data, serverA and Server B has lots of records. So I want to reduce the lines by folding them

```
Envriment   Team    ServerName  LocalGroupName  Permission  SubGroupMember
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  ss
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  dd
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  ab
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  Administrator
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  dd
E1AB    DP  ServerA Remote Desktop Users    RO  dd
E1AB    DP  ServerA Remote Desktop Users    RO  yy
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  yy
E1AB    DP  ServerA Administrators  RW  kk
E1AB    DP  ServerB Remote Desktop Users    RO  kk
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  ff
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  kk
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  pp
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  qq
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  ee
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  rr
E1AB    DP  ServerB Administrators  RW  u
```

When click Server A in html, then the data display

```
Envriment   Team    ServerName          
E1AB    DP  ServerA         
Administrators  RW  ss      
Administrators  RW  dd      
Administrators  RW  ab      
Administrators  RW  Administrator       
Administrators  RW  dd      
Remote Desktop Users    RO  dd      
Remote Desktop Users    RO  yy      
Administrators  RW  yy      
Administrators  RW  kk
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled anything? The answer is:yes this can be done but no ones going to sling you teh codez

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Additionally you might take a look at [Powershell.org](https://powershell.org/ebooks/) they have an ebook section. Search for HTML reporting!